# concatenation in array names

Tags: tcl

I want to store details of 100 nodes in 100 arrays.
For example,

> neighbors of `node 1` should be stored in `array1`

In this, for each array the names should be changed like `array1`, `array2`, `array3`, ..., `array100`

I need the concatenation for array and ( 1 , 2 , 3 , ... , 100 ) using `for` loop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure what you want, but a two dimensional array sounds like the way to go

```
set a(1,1) neighbourof1_1;
set a(1,2) neighbourof1_2;
set a(2,1) neighbourof2_1;
...
...
set a(100,1) neighbourof100_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually recommended to use 2D arrays (really just composite element names) like this:

```
foreach x $listOf1to100 {
    foreach y $listOf1to100 {
        set ary($x,$y) "blah blah"
    }
}
```

However, if you really want to be creating those names then you can do it in several ways. One is like this:

```
foreach x $listOf1to100 {
    set ary${x}(...) "blah blah"
}
```

But that's ugly. It's even uglier when you come to read the arrays! A better choice is this:

```
foreach x $listOf1to100 {
    upvar 0 array$x a
    set a(...) "blah blah"
}
```

Mind you, if you're really doing 2D compact numeric indices then you're perhaps better to use nested lists to build a matrix:

```
# Create
set matrix [lrepeat 100 [lrepeat 100 "blah blah"]]
# Lookup
set value [lindex $matrix $x $y]
# Update
lset matrix $x $y $value
```